# How to close a modified and executing `futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver` stream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'd like to be able to do something along these lines in order to close a `Receiver` stream asynchronously:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;

use futures::future::lazy;
use futures::stream::AndThen;
use futures::sync::mpsc::Receiver;
use futures::{Future, Sink, Stream};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use tokio::timer::{Delay, Interval};

fn main() {
    tokio::run(lazy(|| {
        let (tx, rx) = futures::sync::mpsc::channel(1000);

        let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::<Option<AndThen<Receiver<u32>, _, _>>>::new(None));

        {
            let mut and_then = arc.lock().unwrap();
            *and_then = Some(rx.and_then(|num| {
                println!("{}", num);
                Ok(())
            }));
        }

        let arc_clone = arc.clone();
        // This is the part I'd like to be able to do
        // After one second, close the `Receiver` so that future
        // calls to the `Sender` don't call the callback above in the
        // closure passed to `rx.and_then`
        tokio::spawn(
            Delay::new(std::time::Instant::now() + std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
                .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Some delay err {:?}", e))
                .and_then(move |_| {
                    let mut maybe_stream = arc_clone.lock().unwrap();
                    match maybe_stream.take() {
                        Some(stream) => stream.into_inner().close(),
                        None => eprintln!("Can't close non-existent stream"), // line "A"
                    }
                    Ok(())
                }),
        );

        {
            let mut maybe_stream = arc.lock().unwrap();
            let stream = maybe_stream.take().expect("Stream already ripped out"); // line "B"

            let rx = stream.for_each(|_| Ok(()));
            tokio::spawn(rx);
        }

        tokio::spawn(
            Interval::new_interval(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10))
                .take(10)
                .map_err(|e| {
                    eprintln!("Interval error?! {:?}", e);
                })
                .fold((tx, 0), |(tx, i), _| {
                    tx.send(i as u32)
                        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Send error?! {:?}", e))
                        .map(move |tx| (tx, i + 1))
                })
                .map(|_| ()),
        );

        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0f29de2d2065d081cc346cc31165c26)

However, line A runs because I have to move the stream on line B in order to call `.for_each` on it. If I don't call `.for_each` (or something like it), I can't execute the `AndThen` at all, as far as I know. I can't call `.for_each` without actually moving the object because `for_each` is a moving method.

Is it possible for me to do what I'm trying to do? This seems like it should definitely be possible, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using futures at 0.1 and tokio at 0.1.

Comment: To add, I think I could have included *no* code snippet at all, and this would have been a high enough quality question. The code snippet was just to illustrate one possible approach that I know doesn't work as well as an explanation as to why it doesn't work. The question is what approach would work.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm confused about why you'd need to compile it to answer the question. I don't want to fix the code snippet: I want to find a code snippet that works. The code snippet is fundamentally flawed from top to bottom.

Comment: *included no code snippet at all* — such a question might be on topic perhaps, but people also tend to look unfavorably on questions without any attempt to solve it, so such a question might be downvoted.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly why I included a snippet in the first place. I wanted to show that I'd tried something, and what I'd tried, and why it didn't work. Potential answers don't really need to consider what was wrong with the approach, especially when the question clearly states why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going to lie, I'm with @shepmaster on this one, your question is pretty unclear. That said, it *feels* like you're trying to do something the `mpsc` part of `futures` isn't geared to do.

Anyway. Explanation time.

Whenever you combine/compose streams (or futures!), every single composition method takes `self`, not `&self` or `&mut self` as I think you might have hoped.

The moment you get to this code block of yours:

```
    {
        let mut maybe_stream = arc.lock().unwrap();
        let stream = maybe_stream.take().expect("Stream already ripped out"); // line "B"

        let rx = stream.for_each(|_| Ok(()));
        tokio::spawn(rx);
    }
```

...The stream is extracted from the `Arc<Option<Receiver<T>>>` when you `take()` it, and the content of it is replaced by `None`. You then spawn it on the Tokio reactor, which starts processing this part. This `rx` is now on the loop, and no longer available to you. Additionally, your `maybe_stream` now contains `None`.

After a delay, you then try to `take()` the content of the `Arc<Option<Receiver<T>>>` (line A). Since there's now nothing left, you're left with nothing, and therefore there is nothing left to close. Your code errors out.

Instead of passing around a `mpsc::Receiver` and hoping to destroy it, use a mechanism to stop the stream itself. You can do so yourself or you can use a crate like `stream-cancel` to do so for you.

The DIY version is here, modified from your code:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;

use futures::future::lazy;
use futures::{future, Future, Sink, Stream};
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::sync::atomic::{Ordering, AtomicBool};
use tokio::timer::{Delay, Interval};

fn main() {
    tokio::run(lazy(|| {
        let (tx, rx) = futures::sync::mpsc::channel(1000);

        let circuit_breaker:Arc<AtomicBool> = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        let c_b_copy = Arc::clone(&circuit_breaker);
        tokio::spawn(
            Delay::new(std::time::Instant::now() + std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
                .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Some delay err {:?}", e))
                .and_then(move |_| {
                    // We set the CB to true in order to stop processing of the stream
                    circuit_breaker.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
                    Ok(())
                }),
        );

        {
            let rx2 = rx.for_each(|e| {
                println!("{:?}", e);
                Ok(())
            });
            tokio::spawn(rx2);
        }

        tokio::spawn(
            Interval::new_interval(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100))
                .take(100)
                // take_while causes the stream to continue as long as its argument returns a future resolving to true.
                // In this case, we're checking every time if the circuit-breaker we've introduced is false
                .take_while(move |_| {
                    future::ok(
                        c_b_copy.load(Ordering::Relaxed) == false
                    );
                })
                .map_err(|e| {
                    eprintln!("Interval error?! {:?}", e);
                })
                .fold((tx, 0), |(tx, i), _| {
                    tx.send(i as u32)
                        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Send error?! {:?}", e))
                        .map(move |tx| (tx, i + 1))
                })
                .map(|_| ()),
        );

        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae97065c3d0f05377642d88e1e767950)

The added `take_while()` allows you to operate on either the stream's content, or an outside predicate, to continue or to stop a stream. Note that even though we're using an `AtomicBool`, we still need the `Arc` due to `'static` lifetime requirements from Tokio.

### Reversing the flow

After some discussion in the comments, [this solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd352c443a1866492b605eca43d7fdaa) may be more suited for your use case. I effectively implemented a fan-out stream covered by a circuit breaker. The magic happens here:

```
impl<S> Stream for FanOut<S> where S:Stream, S::Item:Clone {

    type Item = S::Item;

    type Error = S::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Option<S::Item>>, S::Error> {
        match self.inner.as_mut() {
            Some(ref mut r) => {
                let mut breaker = self.breaker.write().expect("Poisoned lock");
                match breaker.status {
                    false => {
                        let item = r.poll();
                        match &item {
                            &Ok(Async::Ready(Some(ref i))) => {
                                breaker.registry.iter_mut().for_each(|sender| {
                                    sender.try_send(i.clone()).expect("Dead channel");
                                });
                                item
                            },
                            _ => item
                        }
                    },
                    true => Ok(Async::Ready(None))
                }
            }
            _ => {

                let mut breaker = self.breaker.write().expect("Poisoned lock");
                // Stream is over, drop all the senders

                breaker.registry = vec![];
                Ok(Async::Ready(None))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the status indicator is set to false, the above stream is polled; the result is then sent to all listeners. If the result of the `poll` is `Async::Ready(None)` (indicating that the stream is finished), all listener channels are closed.

If the status indicator is set to true, all listener channels are closed, and the stream returns `Async::Ready(None)` (and is dropped from execution by Tokio).

The `FanOut` object is cloneable, but only the initial instance will do anything.

Comment: The `.take_until` approach is interesting. In the meantime, I've implemented a similar approach that actually drops the `tx` and checks whether the `tx` has been dropped inside the `fold` (this makes more sense given the code I'm actually writing outside of the scope of the question). I was really hoping to achieve this from the `Receiver` side however, rather than from the `Sender` side. This is because my `Sender`s are organized in a structure, while my `Receiver`s are given to the client which will treat them as "special".

Comment: As such, as a direct answer to the question, I think the `stream-cancel` library is more suitable -- it allows me to do exactly what I want to do. I will need to benchmark, however, as I want to make sure it's not going to harm the performance of the nominal flow.

Comment: The `return` in the `take_while` is non-idiomatic.

Comment: @RiverTam the clue was in the name: `mpsc` - multiple producers, single consumer. You could *also* send your receiver into a fan-out structure (I've had to write my own on this once after trying to adapt `spmc`. Not sure if there is a crate fully satisfying your need) and start/stop consumers as a result.

The `take_while()` explicitely does what `stream-cancel` does under the hood. The [source](https://github.com/jonhoo/stream-cancel/blob/master/src/wrapper.rs#L25) of it uses virtually the same construct :-)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Yes, before trying all of this I was looking into mpmc or spmc solutions, but I found nothing that worked exactly how I wanted, so I ended up going with my own solution. `multiqueue` does what I want, but it has a bug in it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711246/tokio-with-multiqueue-sometimes-hangs-sometimes-works). Crossbeam channels also offer a broadcast I think, but they don't work with tokio as far as I could tell.

Comment: The `take_while` solution would make a lot of sense if the `tx` weren't in a structure. It's clearly a correct approach for the situation posed in the question, but it happens to be the wrong solution for me. Wrapping the `rx` with the canceler happens to be what I want. I'm still testing though, so I may have to keep my  more explicit approach.

Comment: @RiverTam if none of the crates suit you (I know none of them did for the project I was on a year ago - had a similar problem), you could roll your own. I'll jot down an example for you

Comment: @SébastienRenauld that would be awesome. I think it's high time Rust/tokio had something like this. I think it would be excellent as well for those of us coming from JS who love the event emitter/observable pattern (as that's really what a broadcaster is). I've been considering publishing the work I'm doing as its own crate. As of yesterday, it was benchmarking at nearly as efficient as just doing the work synchronously in the interval.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer simply because it offers both options, but I could see arguments for both or neither being correct (neither meaning the correct answer is "there's no way to do this", as neither addresses the problem head-on, though `stream-cancel` gets very close). Someone please let me know if this is not proper SO etiquette. As for my problem in particular, `FnBox` will make the `stream-cancel` approach more viable, but we're on stable and an approach very similar to the manual approach works well enough and benchmarks very well.

Comment: @RiverTam edited my answer with a 15-minute effort into making a fan-out stream with a single flow control element

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Nice! It looks good. Thanks for the taking the time. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a crate like [stream-cancel](https://crates.io/crates/stream-cancel) to achieve this. Here, I've used the [`Valved`](https://docs.rs/stream-cancel/0.4.4/stream_cancel/struct.Valved.html) stream wrapper which takes an existing stream and returns a value you can use to cancel the stream later on:

```
use futures::{
    future::lazy,
    {Future, Sink, Stream},
}; // 0.1.25
use stream_cancel::Valved; // 0.4.4
use tokio::timer::{Delay, Interval}; // 0.1.13

fn main() {
    tokio::run(lazy(|| {
        let (tx, rx) = futures::sync::mpsc::channel(1000);
        let (trigger, rx) = Valved::new(rx);

        tokio::spawn({
            rx.for_each(|num| {
                println!("{}", num);
                Ok(())
            })
        });

        tokio::spawn({
            Delay::new(std::time::Instant::now() + std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
                .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Some delay err {:?}", e))
                .map(move |_| trigger.cancel()),
        });

        tokio::spawn({
            Interval::new_interval(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10))
                .take(10)
                .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Interval error?! {:?}", e))
                .fold((tx, 0), |(tx, i), _| {
                    tx.send(i)
                        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Send error?! {:?}", e))
                        .map(move |tx| (tx, i + 1))
                })
                .map(|_| ()),
        });

        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

The crate has other types suited for subtly different usecases, be sure to check out the documentation.

See [Sébastien Renauld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916268/155423) for one way of implementing this yourself.